# automating mouse clicks for an application

Tags: vbscript

I created a vb script to automate mouse clicks for an application. The script works all along but the last line is not working. I am really confused why would that be if the rest of it is working. I want to click CTRL+K, but somehow this is not working. Here is the code.

```
Option Explicit
 Dim x
 set x=createobject("wscript.shell")

x.run"C:\OnBasewebsite\obclnt32.exe"
 wscript.sleep 2000

 x.sendkeys"MANAGER"

 x.sendkeys"{tab}"

 x.sendkeys"PASSWORD"

 x.sendkeys"{enter}"

 wscript.sleep 2000

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{UP}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"*-*"

 x.sendkeys"{enter}"

 x.sendkeys"{TAB}"

 x.sendkeys"{enter}"

 wscript.sleep 1000

 x.sendkeys"{CLICK LEFT,50,60}"

 x.sendkeys"^k"
```

Comment: In exactly what way is it "not working"?

Comment: It just hangs in there. technicaly ctrl+k should pull up a dialog box in the application but it does not.

Comment: Troubleshoot a little. Send the application something else instead of Control-K. Maybe the application has already hung before you try to send Control-K. Maybe as a diagnostic, send Control-K at an earlier point in time. See if you can send it at all. Try sending it to a different application - things like that.

Comment: well tried everything. It seems like the alt, shift and CTRL functions are not working at all within the application, but when I do manually it works. So, is there something else that I need to add to the code to make this work these control codes to work.

Comment: The alt,ctrl,shift works for when I try to automate within the notepad but not within the application.

Comment: have you tried with "{ }" (curly braces)

Comment: `SendKeys` is extremely unreliable and should be avoided. I'd recommend using a GUI automation tool like [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

Answer (score 0):

use it:

```
  x.sendkeys("^{k}")
```

at place of

```
  x.sendkeys"^k"
```